Trying to recover .frm with dbsake gives me decode issue
I'm trying to recover some table structures with dbsake and it worked fine on first couple files but now its giving me errors on the last two tables.
This is the full error log.
   Uncaught exception!Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./dbsake/dbsake/cli/__init__.py", line 106, in handle_uncaught_exception
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "./dbsake/__main__.py", line 22, in <module>
  File "./dbsake/__main__.py", line 18, in main
  File "./dbsake/dbsake/cli/__init__.py", line 123, in main
  File "./dbsake/click/core.py", line 722, in __call__
  File "./dbsake/click/core.py", line 697, in main
  File "./dbsake/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
  File "./dbsake/click/core.py", line 895, in invoke
  File "./dbsake/click/core.py", line 535, in invoke
  File "./dbsake/click/decorators.py", line 17, in new_func
  File "./dbsake/dbsake/cli/cmd/frm.py", line 71, in frmdump
  File "./dbsake/dbsake/cli/cmd/frm.py", line 26, in parse_and_print
  File "./dbsake/dbsake/core/mysql/frm/__init__.py", line 41, in parse
  File "./dbsake/dbsake/core/mysql/frm/binaryfrm.py", line 402, in parse
  File "./dbsake/dbsake/core/mysql/frm/binaryfrm.py", line 314, in unpack_columns
  File "./dbsake/dbsake/core/mysql/frm/charsets.py", line 1151, in lookup
LookupError: Charset id '0' not found

I've tried looking up online but can't find anything related to dbsake and how to fix it just .csv/xml files and such.
Any Idea on how to fix it?

If you're a user of dbsake rather than the developer, this is not a programming question.

If you don't know the answer why do you speak?

To let you know that you posted this on the wrong site.
